# How convert three of list to map in DART?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to group three lists inside one only map .
that is the three lists.

```
main() {
  var baselist = [1, 5, 7];

  var swlist = ['sw1', 'sw2', 'sw3'];

  var getlist = ['on', 'off', 'on', 
                 'off', 'on', 'off',
                 'on', 'off', 'on'];
}
```

I want it to be like this map :

```
{
 1: {sw1: on, sw2: off, sw3: on},
 5: {sw1: off, sw2: on, sw3: off},
 7: {sw1: on, sw2: off, sw3: on}
}
```

With the note that every element in `baselist` is constant for `swlist` elements, and every three elements in `getlist` will be the values of `swlist`.
then what is the code that converts that lists to one map????

I hope that I explained the problem well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
  var baselist = [1, 5, 7];

  var swlist = ['sw1', 'sw2', 'sw3'];

  var getlist = ['on', 'off', 'on', 
                 'off', 'on', 'off',
                 'on', 'off', 'on'];
  Map resultMap = {};
  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < baselist.length; i++) {
    Map innerMap = {};
    for (int j = 0; j<swlist.length; i++) {
      innerMap[swlist[j]] = getlist[index];
      index++
    }
    
    resultMap[baselist[i]] = innerMap;
  }
  
  print(resultMap);
}
```

Comment: every time I running the program, it stops and not print anything ??? did you test that code? thanks

Comment: there is problem here , when if ` I=1 ` ,for example  then calling `getlist[i*j]` at` j=0 `you expect to be `getlist[3]` but it will `getlist[0]` . and so on ..... i think to write code such as 
``` int x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < baselist.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < swlist.length; j++) {
      innermap[swlist[j]] = getlist[x];
      x++; 
    }
    print(x);
    resultmap[list[i]] = innermap;
  }
  print(resultmap);
}  ```

Comment: You are right @ahmedzahran, I have edited my answer to reflect a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  var baselist = [1, 5, 7];

  var swlist = ['sw1', 'sw2', 'sw3'];

  var getlist = ['on', 'off', 'on',
    'off', 'on', 'off',
    'on', 'off', 'on'];

  Map finalMap = {};

  int start = 0;
  for (var base in baselist) {
    Map<String, String> inner = {};

    swlist.asMap().forEach((key, value) {
      inner[value] = getlist[start + key];
    });

    finalMap[base] = inner;
    start += 3; // next 3 for getlist
  }
  print(finalMap);
```